# Configuration to not wrapping results with Observable.of in TypeScript / Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, nswag

I´m using NSwagStudio (toolchain v10.1.6309.31527) and generating a TypeScript Client for Version 2.0 and template=angular.

Is there any way to configure results to not be wrapped with like return Observable.of(result200);?

I just want it like in previous version (v9.12.6284.27589). Like return result200;

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UseTransformResultMethod setting to transform a result before it is returned by the client.

https://github.com/NSwag/NSwag/issues/721